# How to reset a broken TTY?

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, tty

My Slackware TTY can be broken easily by running:

```
cat some_binary_file
```

After the command, the entire TTY will no longer display readable characters but still responds to keyboard events.

Even if I logout and login again, the TTY is still broken and does not show readable characters anymore. I must restart the machine to restore normal TTY operation.

Is there a solution without restarting entire machine?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Run `echo ^v^o`, that is `echo` and then `Ctrl-v` and then `Ctrl-o`, Enter. You will not see the `Ctrl-v`. It will display as `echo ^O`. `Ctrl-v` sets it into verbose mode, passing through control characters, and the `Ctrl-o` will reset the terminal.

Comment: Just a short hint: If the TTY is completely unusable or a logging console you can reset it easily from any other TTY with `echo ^v^o > /dev/ttyN` where N is the number of the terminal.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on MacOSX (10.11.6) / iTerm2 (3.0.12) / bash (4.1.2)

Comment: I get a `permission denied` on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Answer (score 49):

Usually, running `reset` resets the terminal. Some key bindings from `.inputrc` might be lost, though.

Comment: Super simple solution that fixed my crashed tmux oh-my-zsh pane.

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer in my opinion. When you cannot see what you are typing is easier to type `reset` and hit enter than trying to use key combinations, plus, it works 100% of the times.

Comment: This fixed line select copy/paste not wrapping at end of terminal in Cygwin. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

You can try the ANSI reset command:

```
printf "\033c"
```

Comment: this is the only one that worked on OpenBSD 5.4

Comment: This also worked from the shell (bash) as
echo -e '\033c'

Comment: @EdRandall Yes. Note that "echo -e" is not supported by all shells while `printf` has the advantage of being portable so works whatever the shell, including bash.

Comment: I imagine that this has nothing to do with the seagull diacritic in IPA? U+033C ‹◌̼› \N{COMBINING SEAGULL BELOW}

Comment: @TRiG Indeed. Nothing to do either with the famous [Eric Cantona's quote.](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/when-the-seagulls-follow-the-trawler-it-is-because-they-think-sardines-will-be-thrown-into-the-sea-1613641.html) ;-)

Comment: It works in gdb too, to clear the inferior's tty: `show inferior-tty` then `!echo -ne '\033c' > /dev/pts/XXX` using `XXX` just shown

Answer (score 12):

My terminal didnt display any characters I typed. None of the other tricks worked. This one works:

```
stty sane
```

Worked for me. I sometimes have a terminal in an unresponsive state, but none of the other suggestions could give me the output back again. The other suggestions I tried, but didn't work:

```
echo ^v^o
reset
printf "\033c"
```

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79686/53236

Answer (score 0):

There are actually a few potential problems, and it might have to do with your environment. First off, as @Jesper answered, you want to do `stty sane`. However, you might not even be able to set up the environment correctly with that.

This is due to the difference between `/bin/bash` and `/bin/sh`. Upon opening your tty, run `/bin/bash` and then try `stty sane`. This should fix everything. Finally, I recommend adding such a thing to .bashrc

Another option would be to install a sane tty software.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import subprocess
    def clear():
    if name == 'nt':
            _ = system('cls')
    else:
            _ = system('clear')
            subprocess.run(["reset"])
```

This works for me, my shell is /bin/bash, my enviroment is Windows 11, SWL and Python 3.8

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).