# Command clear is not clearing screen

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, reset, tty

Follow up on [How to reset a broken TTY?](https://superuser.com/questions/640338/how-to-reset-a-broken-tty),
to fix the terminal after displaying a binary file,

I've tried all solution there, as well as those from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79684/

But my case is still not covered --

- the command clear is not clearing screen
- using arrow-up key to see previous commands, but if there is a shorter command comes after a longer one, the longer part still remains

to reproduce the case:

```
cat /bin/ls
clear
# clear is not clearing screen
```

How to fix that?

PS, my system:

```
$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux bullseye/sid
Release:        testing
Codename:       bullseye

$ echo $TERM
screen
```

I.e., it's `screen` session running under `xterm`.

Comment: I would guess that the terminal has changed modes and is not now in a 'text' mode.  Read the Manual.  Without knowing the brand and model, there is little that can be done.

Comment: Does running `stty sane` help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `reset` command.

Simply type `reset` and press Enter a few times.

If this doesn't work then your `TERM` environment  variable is not set correctly for some reason.  Try `export TERM=xterm` then do `reset` again.  To permanently fix it you may need to put `export TERM=xterm` in your `~/.bashrc` or similar.

Comment: Recently installed Ubuntu 20.04: `echo $TERM` => `xterm-256color`

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198794/where-does-the-term-environment-variable-default-get-set

Comment: I've update my OP with more info, mainly, I'm having `screen` session running under `xterm`. I tried reset, then `export TERM=xterm` then do `reset` again. but it is still not working. So I suspend `screen`, did above again, and reconnect to `screen`, and now it is working as expected. thanks

Comment: Ops, my BS is still not working, under the old screen session, regardless what I tried. it is just showing `^H`. Anyway I can correct that myself?

Comment: Note to myself, to reset a broken `screen` TTY, quit screen, do `reset` in tty, then get back into screen again.